# Inconsistent data being downloaded from Yahoo Finance website

Tags: python, download, python-requests

I've written a script in python to download csv files from Yahoo finance (one for each stock) containing historical stock data for various stocks I'm interested in. I then use the data to perform correlation analysis.

In the midst of running the code multiple times today, I realized that I kept getting different figures when performing the correlation analysis. On tracking back, I realize that each time I ran the script, the csv files I downloaded for some stocks would contain historical data for different periods.

> For example, on the first try, the csv file for stock A would contain data from 01/01/2000 to 17/07/2020. On the second occasion just a few minutes later, the csv file for stock A would now contain data from 01/01/2010 to 17/07/2020.

This was the case even though the parameters I used did not change each time. I'm unable to figure out what's the issue and would appreciate any help or pointers.

My code as follows:

```
stistocks = ["U96.SI", "D01.SI", "J36.SI", "O39.SI", "BN4.SI", "N2IU.SI", "BS6.SI", "G13.SI", "V03.SI", "S63.SI", "F34.SI", "S68.SI", "C52.SI", "Z74.SI",
"A17U.SI", "U11.SI", "H78.SI", "M44U.SI", "C31.SI", "U14.SI", "J37.SI", "T39.SI", "C6L.SI", "S58.SI", "D05.SI", "C38U.SI", "C09.SI", "C61U.SI", "C07.SI", "Y92.SI", "A35.SI"]

params = {"period1":946857600, "period2":1595030400, "interval": "1d", "events": "history"}

headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
             'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
             'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
             'Dnt': '1',
             'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
             'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4)'
                           'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                           'Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[ 502, 503, 504 ])
s.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    
for stock in stistocks:
    url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{}".format(stock)
    data = s.get(url, params = params)
    with open("{}.csv".format(stock), "wb") as f:
        f.write(data.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would explore alternatives like https://finnhub.io/

Comment: I have. The problem is that I'm looking for data on stocks listed on the Singapore exchange and not many (if at all) carry it, apart from Yahoo finance.